# The program can't start because opencl.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: opencl

I have a Geforce 210 and windows 10 64bit and I want to run a simple program with opencl.

I installed latest cuda sdk and setup the project following instructions in [this link](https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2015-03-16/how-to-install-opencl-on-windows/) with a little changes regarding environment variables.

Anyways, the project builds now but at runtime shows error dialog complaining about missing **opencl.dll** as the topic says. I looked up in the registry **HKLM/software/khronos/opencl/vendors** and there is an entry with the name **C:\Windows\System32\nvopencl.dll**. I looked in system32 folder and the file is not there. I searched opencl in system32 folder and three results where found:

- **opencl.dll** in *C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\rdvgwddmdx11.inf_amd64_cedfb27d9d08d0a0*
- **opencl32.dll** and **opencl64.dll** in *C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_4e97579e23acb4ca*

What is going on and what should I do to run the simple program? The program source is just a couple of lines:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<CL/cl.h>

int main()
{
  cl_int err;
  cl_uint numPlatforms;

  err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
  if (CL_SUCCESS == err)
    printf("\nDetected OpenCL platforms: %d", numPlatforms);
  else
    printf("\nError calling clGetPlatformIDs. Error code: %d", err);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I changed the mentioned registry key to point to the **opencl.dll** in the weird directory and now the program works and find the device. Now the question is what is wrong with NVIDIA graphics driver installer? Does it point to wrong location in other hardware too?